# JVM debug port 7779 is in use

Tags: java, ibm-rad

I am using RAD 8. When I start the server in debug mode, it displays a error message states that `JVM debug port 7779 is in use`. I had this problem many times as I know this port was used by RAD. So I had to stop the process with **image name "Java" under Window Task Manager>Processes**. `But however for the first time I face this issue without no such "java" process running in Window task manager`. In my knowledge none of the IBM product does use this port presently. **I have even tried to restart my system and started the RAD, but still the issue remained same.**

I deleted the profile and re-created a new one. After that I started in debug more. And it started without any error.

But again to get all the resources imported from my friends server, I got his .car file. After importing this I started the server and got the same issue. Now wondering what could cause this port used issue when just importing the .car file.

1. **Can you please tell me how to know which application uses this port and how to stop it**
2. **Is there a way I can change the debug port while creating the server profile? I tried to see the debug port in profile creation but didn't find anywhere.**

Friends please share me if you have any input. I will share if I get the root cause of this

Comment: I'm not big on Windows, but I'm pretty sure you can discover the process listening on specific port (or at least its pid) with `netstat`. Look [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/netstat-tips-and-tricks-for-windows-server-admins/3371/) and [there](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/p/netstat-command.htm).

Comment: Thanks @incarnate I will go thru this and try my luck :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I got the issue fixed. I was able to change the debug port number. Below are the steps

1. Start the server in normal mode (ctrl+Alt+R).
2. Go to application server configuration window.
3. Click on Debugging service under "Additional properties"
4. Update the **JVM debug port** e.g. 7780
5. Update **JVM debug arguments** for address e.g. refer the address=7780 for the below entry

> -Dcom.ibm.ws.classloader.j9enabled=true -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,**address=7780**

6. Click on apply
7. Click on save
8. Stop the server
9. Start the server in debug mode (ctrl+Alt+D).

[image: Below are the screenshot where you can change the port.]

Comment: Sorry but this in an incorrect "answer". Please could you delete it and copy the text into the question instead?

Comment: Hi @andyb, thanks for your suggestion. I have edited the question. However I got the answer and posted here.

Comment: Good work and thanks for posting a solution! `+1`. Don't forget you can accept your own answer (after a timeout) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Response to your first question:
Open the command line and enter the following command to list all the port numbers(IP with port number) and the process id for the respective port: `netstat -ano`
You can kill the process for the required port with the command : `taskkill -f /PID <PID_NO>`

For instance, you'll see four columns something like 0:0:0:port_no and 
1234(last column - PID)
then execute the command taskkill -f /PID 1234.